# Scale a class of different images to parent, but not larger than their original size

Tags: css

How do I scale an image fluidly to the width of its parent container, but not larger than its own original width.

E.g. if I have an image that is 500px wide, I don't want it do get larger than that, but I want it to scale down with its parent container when the parent is narrower than 500px.

```
width: 100%;
max-width: 500px;
```

works, but what do I do, if I need to define a CSS rule for a class of images of different sizes? Is this possible without JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `max-width:100%`. On the following example, the original image width is 245px, and the 3rd div is wider than it.

```css
img {
  max-width:100%;
}

#a {
  width:80px;
  background:yellowgreen; 
}

#b {
  width:160px;
  background:gold; 
}

#c {
  width:320px;
  background:tomato; 
}

div {
  float: left; 
}
```

```html
<div id=a><img src="http://i.imgur.com/74sI3aX.gif" alt=img></div>
<div id=b><img src="http://i.imgur.com/74sI3aX.gif" alt=img></div>
<div id=c><img src="http://i.imgur.com/74sI3aX.gif" alt=img></div>
```

Comment: What if any one of those divs have width more than 500px?

Comment: The image on the example have 245px and the 3rd div width is bigger than it (320px). Anyway, you can play with it [**on this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1n945ycw/)

Comment: Alright, so image does not exceeds its orignal size.Nice, thanks for the example :)

Comment: I'm going to add it to the answer, thanks for the warning.